# set OnClick property of dynamically created asp:button

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, onclick

I have a button which needs to get created dynamically but the problem is I cannot set the OnClick property of it for it to run the server side method btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

If I do:

```
btnSubmit.Attributes["OnClick"] = "btnSubmit_Click()";
```

it actually adds it to the OnClientClick instead.

```
btnSubmit.Click += new EventHandler(btnSubmit_Click);
```

also never fires.

How can I set the actual server OnClick?

Comment: Are you creating your button inseide Page_Init / Page_PreInit?

Comment: did you place Runat = server tag?

Comment: @alliswell, he is creating the button programatically

Comment: it is created in page_load, it is in a table which is also created programatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind event in Page_PreInit

```
 public Button btnSubmit; // Add the on class level as data member

Protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       btnSubmit = new Button();        
       btnSubmit.Text = "Click me";           
       btnSubmit.Click +=new EventHandler(btnSubmit_Click);
       this.form1.Controls.Add(btnSubmit); 
}
```

Add this event.

```
void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: Just tried it, it still does not fire. I suppose as a hack i can make create the button on the aspx and then copy it into the respective cell. Hacky but it works

Comment: Where you instantiate button ?

Comment: I have updated my answer and this is tested code and must run.

Comment: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Comment: So you got the postback, add this EnableEventValidation = "false" in page tag <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" EnableViewState="true" EnableEventValidation = "false" %>

Answer (score 2):

```
btnSubmit.Click += new EventHandler(btnSubmit_Click);
```

//Your event handler

```
void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: forgot to mention, tried that too. never fires. Is there a way to set runat=server in c# code?

Comment: really ?? where are you adding the button and the event handler ?

Comment: you need to do it in page_init

Comment: ... or Page_PreInit if your page have no master page associated.